# IE-9 taking value of placeholder as a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have HTML as:

```
<input id="SLOCriteriaOtherText" name="SLOCriteriaOtherText" style="width: 100%;" type="text" data-role="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter name for 'other' metric..." class="k-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-owns="SLOCriteriaOtherText_listbox" aria-autocomplete="list">
```

I just wanted to validate it for blank textbox checking.

Above textbox has placeholder as:

```
Enter name for 'other' metric...
```

I have done validation as for blank textbox checking as:

```
  if ($("#SLOCriteriaOtherText").val() == "") {

                alertMessageText += "Please enter Other criteria text. \n";
            }
```

It works fine on Chrome.

But does not work on Internet Explorer.

When i alert the value of SLOCriteriaOtherText from internet explorer, It shows me value of placeholder. I.E.

```
Enter name for 'other' metric...
```

By this validation fails on Internet explorer and works on crome.

Please help me.

How can i take value of `SLOCriteriaOtherText` without placeholder on internet Explorer (Version 9)

Comment: Are you using a template or library or sth, [`placeholder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not supported in IE<10, and it's treated as a regular custom attribute. Also `data*` is not supported in IE9...

Comment: You are probably using something like [placeholder.js](http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/) library to make placeholders work on IE9.. Which uses 'value' attribute to display the text..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this jQuery IE Placeholder library. IE sucks with placeholders :)

http://www.moreonfew.com/how-to-make-placeholder-work-in-ie/

***Sample usage -***

**Include the JS -**

```
<!-- Include the jQuery file -->

<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Include the jquery.placeholder.js file -->

<script src="jquery.placeholder.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Define your DOM**

```
<input type="text" name="emailAddress" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
<textarea name="about" placeholder="Tell us about yourself" />
```

**Placehold it :)**

```
<!-- Apply the placeholder functionality to elements 
  using appropriate jquery selectors -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[type=text], textarea').placeholder();
</script>
```